# Google maps sending multiple requests of map tiles

Tags: javascript, performance, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, pagespeed

The google maps api is sending multiple requests of map tiles to my site, not sure what is causing this as I have used the API many times but have never come across this issue.

[image]

Comment: When you pan or zoom the map, the API will send these requests. What's wrong?

Comment: I have never had these request show up just on load before on any site. Now seemingly overnight they have appeared on every site I've built using the Google Maps JS api. When looking at page speed it's adding more request and sites like Gtmetrix are saying 'The requests for the following URLs don't fit in a single packet. Reducing the size of these requests could reduce latency.'

Comment: Anything else to add to this? I've noticed it also now.